# JavaScript page resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that you don't normally like doing things like this but I'm at University and have to do a project with several different stylesheets for the same page. I have been given JavaScript code to enable me to resize the page when the window is resized.

This code works however I am getting a peculiar effect on one of the stylesheets where the content div takes up most of the page when it shouldn't, this page has measurements in ems whereas my other stylesheets use px but I am supposed to use ems for at least one page. Although I could give my lecturer a reason for it being bigger I would prefer to fix the problem. The JavaScript code I am using is shown below:

```
function smoothresize() {
            blockwidth = 59.4; /*This is in ems as per the lecturers request a well and is the size of the container div I created*/
            minmargin = 0;
            minsize = 10;
            emwidth = (minmargin * 2) + blockwidth;
            computeResize(emwidth, minsize, false)
        }

function computeResize(wide, minsize, jerk) {
            windowpixels = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            pixelsize = windowpixels / wide;
            emsize = calculateEmsize(pixelsize, minsize, jerk);
            b = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
            b.style.fontSize = emsize + "em";
        }

function calculateEmsize(psize, minsize, jerk) {
            if (psize > minsize) {
                raw = psize;
            }
            else {
                raw = minsize;
            }
            if (jerk) {
                result = ((Math.floor(raw)) / 16);
            }
            else {
                result = raw / 16;
            }
            return result
        }
```

This is where I have Implemented the code in my XHTML:

```
<body onload="smoothresize()" onresize="smoothresize()">
```

I wouldn't be able to use jQuery as a solution to the problem either, I would only be able to modify the code given.

Any help in this matter Would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your logic might be going wrong in `computeResize` when you set `pixelsize`? If your window is 1000px wide, you then divide that by your width in ems, and get a 'pixelsize' of 16.8, which doesn't seem to relate directly to minsize the way you check it below? You may want to set up an example page, as it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, and what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's user interface plugin. It contains a "resizable" option; you ought to be able to add `<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){};</script>` that loads the desired JQUI function upon page load.